# Unable to install cypress via npm

Tags: node.js, cypress

When I try to install cypress via Visual Studio Code, I am getting the below error.

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
> npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/core@20.1.0.
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by running install command on command prompt outside Visual Studio Code.

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```